# Android images from SD and drawable different sizes

Tags: android-3.0-honeycomb, android

I build an app for Tablets and used some of the pictures from SD card and some from drawable folder.

The thing is if i use images from from SD and show them in my app i can use image with original screen resolution/size to display the on full screen (1280x720) but when i use same image from drawable folder i have to enlarge it 1.5 time bigger to show on full screen (1920x1080). This is not a big issue just curious why is that.

Comment: This sounds as a typical issue related to the different dpi options. The four generalized densities, `lpi`, `mdpi`, `hdpi` and `xhdpi` have 3:4:6:8 scaling ratios, with `mdpi` being the baseline. It sounds like your tablet has an `hdpi` density, which could explain the  1.5 multiplication factor, since `6/4=1.5`. For more details, read the [Supporting Multiple Screens article](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html).

Comment: @MH. you should post that as an answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Repost of an earlier comment, but now as answer (as requested):

This sounds as a typical issue related to the different dpi options. The four generalized densities, `lpi`, `mdpi`, `hdpi` and `xhdpi` have 3:4:6:8 scaling ratios, with `mdpi` being the baseline. It sounds like your tablet has an `hdpi` density, which could explain the 1.5 multiplication factor, since `6/4=1.5`.

For more details, read the [Supporting Multiple Screens article](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html).

Comment: android images from drawable are bigger than images from sdcard. (this answered my question. so I am just adding search keywords)